# Does Python use pointers when creating a new sliced list?

Tags: python, list

So, we know that Python uses a reference system, in order to refer to values in a list. So, if we create a new variable=list[index], the variable points to that list index. But what about when we are slicing a new list? Does the new sliced list use pointers? Or is it a new list in itself?

Comment: slicing makes a copy; there are no `memoryview` for lists. some good info: [Buffer Protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485475/can-i-create-a-view-on-a-python-list)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [understanding list slice assignment in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778010/understanding-list-slice-assignment-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list in Python is made of an array of references (plus some bookkeeping data). Slicing allocates a new array, but those copied references still point to the same heap objects.

When you do `variable=list[index]`, the `variable` does not point to the list index. Rather, it references the same object that the list does at that index (at the time it is looked up; they can be changed independently later).